# Why pandas_alive raised error:RuntimeError: Ensure that a matplotlib writer library is installed

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

As per title, I using `pandas_alive` to try make a gif. But when I try using `plot_animated()` from `pda(pandas_alive)` it raised

> error:RuntimeError: Ensure that a matplotlib writer library is installed, see https://github.com/JackMcKew/pandas_alive/blob/main/README.md#requirements for more details

Here is the total script that I write with Python 3.8.5 and Anaconda.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_alive as pda
import matplotlib
df=pd.read_csv("worldometer_data.csv")
cros=pd.crosstab(df["Country/Region"],df["TotalCases"])
cros.plot_animated(kind="line",filename="dis.gif")
```

Comment: Is it the same if I modify it to `import pandas_alive` only?

Comment: i dont know,this code that i just wrote for my professor cause he wanna a gif pic,but the thing is here